# Check whether file is binary

Tags: r, binaryfiles

I would like to have a function `is.binary` that gives the following results

```
tmp_vec=1:3

save(tmp_vec,file="temp_vec.RData")
write.csv(tmp_vec,"temp_vec.csv")

is.binary("temp_vec.RData")
#TRUE

is.binary("temp_vec.csv")
#FALSE
```

Is there a function like this in `R`?
The best solution I was able to come up with is

```
is.binary=function(filename) {
  is_binary=TRUE
  #suppress warnings and try to read file with binary reader
  #if it throws an error, set is_binary to FALSE
  withCallingHandlers(expr=tryCatch(load(filename),
                                    error=function(err) is_binary<<-FALSE),
                      warning=function(w) invokeRestart("muffleWarning"))
  #since R loads the objects of the binary file into the memory, delete them
  #maybe this is unnecessary ... 
  #... I do not know how R handles memory of objects that go out of scope
  rm(list=ls()[ls()!="is_binary"])
  is_binary
}
```

Obviously, this function is not very efficient when dealing with large files. Any pointers to better solutions? Thank you!

Edit: I am on a Windows machine.

Comment: When you say binary, do you mean RData files, since you could try to open a jpeg and it will file your test.

Depending on your needs you may be able to use the existing tools within base R packages https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/tools/html/fileutils.html.

Depending on your OS needs you could always just invoke a script or dll to check file type (such as file) in *nix.

Comment: Oh yes, forgot to mention that I am on Windows. Thanks - will look into `fileutils`.

Comment: @Jonathan Lisic Yes, it will be either data generated by `save` or `write.csv` (or similar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All files on a computer are binary files. The exceptions are those that happen to look like text files. And even those can have different encodings that are required to actually read the files properly.

If you're just trying to distinguish between the results of `save()` and `write.csv()`, the easiest thing to check would be if the file is compressed. By default `save()` will compress a file. You can look for the magic number for compression in the file. Here's one way to do that

```
is_compressed <- function(filename, magic.number=as.raw(c("0x1f","0x8b"))) {
    fh<-file(filename, "rb")
    on.exit(close(fh))
    magic <- readBin(fh, "raw", length(magic.number))
    if(length(magic) != length(magic.number)) return(FALSE)
    if(all(magic == magic.number)) return(TRUE)
    return (FALSE)
}
```

This only requires reading two bytes of a file rather than the whole thing. Once you know it's compressed you can then try to look for the magic number for an rData file. Here's a more complete function

```
is_rdata <- function(filename) {
    #check for magic number
    #https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/b99d403f4b7337553acb2d2108c7a00e6c19f908/src/main/saveload.c#L1786

    fh <- if(!is_compressed(filename))
        file(filename, "rb")
    else {
        gzfile(filename, "rb")
    }
    on.exit(close(fh))


    magic <- rawToChar(readBin(fh, "raw", 5))
    if(nchar(magic)<5) return(FALSE)
    if(magic %in% c("RDA1\n","RDB1\n","RDX1\n","RDA2\n","RDB2\n","RDX2\n")) return(TRUE)
    return (FALSE)
}
```

We can test with

```
dd <- data.frame(a=1:4, b=letters[1:4])

save(dd, file="test1.file")
write.csv(dd, file="test2.file")

is_rdata("test1.file")
is_rdata("test2.file")
```

of course, if you are careful about your file extensions, that would probably be the easiest way to identify files.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! This is a much better approach than mine. I like the "trick" with the compression check.